# Javascript Promisification, why use "call"?

Tags: javascript, callback, this, es6-promise

I want to understand why in the below example, the "call" method was used.

`loadScript` is a function that appends a script tag to a document, and has an optional callback function.

`promisify` returns a wrapper function that in turn returns a promise, effectively converting `loadScript' from a callback-based function to a promise based function.

```
function promisify(f) {
  return function (...args) { // return a wrapper-function 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      function callback(err, result) { // our custom callback for f 
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      }

      args.push(callback); // append our custom callback to the end of f arguments

      f.call(this, ...args); // call the original function
    });
  };
}

// usage:
let loadScriptPromise = promisify(loadScript);
loadScriptPromise(...).then(...);
```

`loadScript()`:

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
  let script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = src;

  script.onload = () => callback(null, script);
  script.onerror = () => callback(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`));

  document.head.append(script);
}
```

I understand that `call` is used to force a certain context during function call, but why not use just use `f(...args)` instead of `f.call(this, ...args)`?

Comment: "*f(...args) instead of f.call(this, ...args)?*" because the value of `this` will not be preserved.

Comment: yes, but why do we need to preserve the value of `this` in this particular situation?

Comment: @Elbasel - Because `promisify` is a **general-purpose** function, and you might use it on a method.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's basically a duplicate, but this is an interesting corner case.

Comment: Note that `promisify` only works on functions whose callbacks take an error and the result as arguments. It was created specifically for Node functions which follow that pattern.

Comment: @Pointy it is a duplicate of many other questions that have asked why a generic utility will preserve `this`. There have been at least a few specifically asked for `debounce`, for example.

Comment: @VLAZ yes I know, but I think something specifically about `promisify()` is worth having for search purposes. That's just my opinion; now that TJ gave an answer, closing it as a dup seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`promisify` is a **general-purpose** function. Granted, you don't care about `this` in `loadScript`, but you would if you were using `promisify` on a method. So this works:

```js
function promisify(f) {
  return function (...args) { // return a wrapper-function 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      function callback(err, result) { // our custom callback for f 
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      }

      args.push(callback); // append our custom callback to the end of f arguments

      f.call(this, ...args); // call the original function
    });
  };
}

class Example {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    method(b, callback) {
        const result = this.a + b;
        setTimeout(() => callback(null, result), 100);
    }
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const e = new Example(40);
        const promisifiedMethod = promisify(e.method);
        const result = await promisifiedMethod.call(e, 2);
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

That wouldn't work if `promisify` didn't use the `this` that the function it returns receives:

```js
function promisifyNoCall(f) {
  return function (...args) { // return a wrapper-function 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      function callback(err, result) { // our custom callback for f 
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      }

      args.push(callback); // append our custom callback to the end of f arguments

      f(...args); // call the original function *** changed
    });
  };
}

class Example {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    method(b, callback) {
        const result = this.a + b;
        setTimeout(() => callback(null, result), 100);
    }
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const e = new Example(40);
        const promisifiedMethod = promisifyNoCall(e.method);
        const result = await promisifiedMethod.call(e, 2);
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a very detailed answer. Can I bother you for some references that will help me understand your usage of `this` and `call`?

Comment: @Elbasel - MDN is a great resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call Also [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). Happy coding!